# trying to click webpage button, getting "error 70 permission denied"

Tags: javascript, html, vba

Below is a snippet of my vba code and html source. Any ideas why I am getting error 70- "permission denied" would be much appreciated! Thank you

```
Dim ent
Set htmldoc = .document
Set ent = htmldoc.frames("Content").document.getElementsByName("EnteredClicked")
ent.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Click **"error 70 happens here"**

frame Name = Content 
<INPUT class=btn1 type=submit value=" Enter " name=EnterClicked>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible reasons, incorrect permissions, getting locked out by another process, etc.. Looking here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264534(v=vs.60).aspx  might help but start by checking file perms and write-protected disks

Comment: I should mention that before I get error 70 I get error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method". Any ideas why that error is popping up? thanks again.

Comment: Check the spellings of your properties and methods, including the entirety of your code might help because you need to find the automation object that is having a non-existant method attempted to be applied to it (not all methods and properties exist for all objects) or the friend procedure being called late bound EDIT: You should fix the 438 error first, it may be related to the error 70, Hope this helps!